# failing to set path to an extended template from child template

Tags: flask, jinja2, relative-path, extends

my flask structure (partial, here):

```
SimpleFlask/mysite/
    flask_app.py
    /templates
        cabwill_base3.htm
        /cabwill
            /pagart
                defaultcontentA.htm
```

This structured is intended as to hold a couple of subsites under /mysite; cabwill being one of them.

My *defaultcontentA.htm* page is supposed to extend : {% extends "*cabwill_base3.htm*" %} , which is living 2 storeys above in the file system.

I tested a couple of relative paths, with no success :-/   :

```
"cabwill_base3.htm"
"./../../cabwill_base3.htm"
```

etc

I googled and stackoverflowed about paths in Flask, but still I'm stuck.

N.B. : The code is working ok when the base template and the child template are in the same folder, but this simplification is not suitable to my project.

How should I do?

Thanks on forward

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to accomplish this using `app.jinja_loader`.

[FileSystemLoader](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/api/?highlight=filesystemloader#jinja2.FileSystemLoader) or [ChoiceLoader](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/api/?highlight=filesystemloader#jinja2.ChoiceLoader).

```py
from flask import Flask
from jinja2 import FileSystemLoader, ChoiceLoader
import pathlib

current_dir = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent

app = Flask(__name__)

# 1- you can pass a ChoiceLoader, therefore if a template could
# not be found by one loader the _next_ one is tried.
app.jinja_loader = ChoiceLoader(
    [
        FileSystemLoader(current_dir / "templates"),
        FileSystemLoader(current_dir / "templates" / "inner_templates"),
    ]
)

# 2- You can pass your template folders in a list and the _first hit_
# will be used.
app.jinja_loader = FileSystemLoader(
    [current_dir / "templates", current_dir / "other_templates"]
)
```